# jQuery/JS: Looking for a way to animate a cube in 3D perspective

Tags: javascript, jquery, 3d

I've been searching for a way to have a JavaScript animation (preferably using jQuery) behave like a rotating 3D cube, similar to this script:

http://keith-wood.name/imageCube.html

What stops me from settling with Keith's solution is the possibility for a more smoother and better transition between the images. Is it possible to make a more realistic version using only JS?

-Staffan

Comment: That's pretty darn nifty. I'd use it; however, be aware that it cheats (in the name of performance?) with the perspective transformation (it's not 3D in the "OpenGL" sense). Well, this cheats as well (I believe it's ray-cast like Wolfenstein): [3D Walker](http://www.benjoffe.com/code/demos/canvascape/), but it's also neat.

Comment: Yes not "true" 3D but rather a mimicking effect is what I'm looking for. This one behaves a bit too jerky.

Answer (score 1):

i've ended up using jQuery.imageCube but previously I've considered :

http://www.kawa.net/works/js/animation/cube-e.html

it's pure JS (no JQuery dependency) - I was able to somehow better understand "how it's done" from it.
although I'm not sure if it ain't still "jerky" just like imageCube ... :)